# GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location .net core

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core, .net-standard

Using VS2017 .net core 1.4 I can get the line of code

```
var z = typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location;
```

to compile if it is in my application project using the Microsoft.NetCore.App SDK.
However, it does not compile when in the Standard class project using the NETStandard.Library SDK.

Similar issues with referencing the `System.Runtime.Loader` assembly.

Any ideas to to how to overcome this.

Thanks
Martin

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: compile. with error 'Assembly' does not contain a definition for 'Location' and no extension method 'Location' accepting a first argument of type 'Assembly'.

Comment: please show what exactly you specify as `TargetFramework`.  Did you call `dotnet restore` after updating to .NET Standard v1.6,1?

Answer (score 0):

The `Location` property of `System.Reflection.Assembly` is only available in .NET Standard 1.5 and higher. So it cannot be used in a `netstandard1.4` project.

Comment: am using v1.6,1. Still does not compile. with error 'Assembly' does not contain a definition for 'Location' and no extension method 'Location' accepting a first argument of type 'Assembly'.